# Devise Admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, admin

I have followed the Devise Wiki to create a very basic admin setup by adding a admin column to my User table in a boolean format.

I have been into my table (through SQlite administrator) and assigned one of my users to be an admin.

I am then have the following code in my view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if current_user.admin? %>
    <%= link_to "Admin Job Post", new_user_job_path(current_user.id) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Post a new job", new_user_job_path(current_user.id) %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Post a new job", new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

The issue I am having is that my app is only ever returning my `<%= link_to "Post a new job", new_user_job_path(current_user.id) %>` even when logged in with an admin user.

It would be great to get a solution on this because I have tried several variations and can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you confirmed that the user is actually signed in, and that `current_user.admin?` returns true?

Comment: The current_user is definitely signed in correctly because all the elements that are only for signed in members are showing. How would I check current_user.admin? returns true?

Comment: You could, for example, add `<%= current_user.admin? === true ? "admin" : "peasant" %>`. Or set a debugger breakpoint and check it in the console.

Comment: Use `rails console` in your command line and then `user = User.where(email: "your@email.com").first` will give you the user. Next check what `user.admin?` shows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the entirety of your code, but I have a similar setup, but I used the following to show a link once a user is logged in as an Admin (I used 'try' due to the fact that it is outside of a 'user_logged_in' check).

```
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
    <li><a href="#">AdminLink</a></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you made the user an admin?
To make the user admin you should have run the following commands

```
User.find(#id_of_user_you_want_to_make_admin)
User.admin = true
User.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if current_user.present? && current_user.has_role?(:admin) %>
    <li><%= link_to 'Some Cool Admin Feature', cool_admin_path %></li>
```

This is what you're looking for if you're using Rails 4 with Devise 2.x. Note the () around :admin aren't necessary, I included them for clarity here as the '?' after the method seems to throw people that are new to ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to give admin privileges is to simply use `<% if current_user.try (:email) == "admin@example.com" %>` That always works for me. That way you don't have to worry about the whole system.